# In a single figure, boxplot of all columns split by a "label" column

Tags: python, boxplot, seaborn

Looking at the [boxplot API page](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html#seaborn.boxplot), I want something that looks like a combination of this:

```
>>> iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
>>> ax = sns.boxplot(data=iris, orient="h", palette="Set2")
```

[image]

Except I want it split by a column that holds a certain label, similarly to what is achieved by the `hue` argument in an example that follows:

```
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips, palette="Set3")
```

[image]

This example only works when `x` and `y` are defined, but for what I want to achieve I want `x` to essentially be every column in my dataframe (except the label, obviously) and `y` to be the frequency, similarly to what is shown in the first example. If not possible to achieve with seaborn, I am willing to try some other visualization library for python.

Comment: Can you use a dummy `x` variable to carry the index? Just `arange(len(y))` I think.

Comment: If I follow correctly, you mean something like `sns.boxplot(data=data, orient='h', hue='target', x=data.index)`?

Doing so got me a boxplot of the indices i.e. `np.arange(len(data))`

edit - pressed `enter` by accident. twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "unstack" or "melt" the data such everything is value, not a variable (long format instead of wide format).

Here's what that looks like:

```
iris_xtab = seaborn.load_dataset("iris")
iris_long = pandas.melt(iris, id_vars='species')
seaborn.boxplot(x='species', y='value', hue='variable', data=iris_long)
```

[image]

Or leaving out the species value as x (you have to assign a dummy value as suggested earlier

```
ax = seaborn.boxplot(x='pos', y='value', hue='variable', 
                     data=iris_long.assign(pos=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will follow this idea. I was looking for something that didn't require me to change the dataframe I was working with, do you know if any other python library would allow that?

Comment: @sissas I don't. And you don't have to change your existing dataframe as my example saves the transformed data in a new object. The original dataframe is not mutated in that operation. If you don't want to add another variable to your namespace, you could `pipe` the result of the `melt` function directly to `seaborn.boxplot`

Comment: yes, of course, but I was still hoping for a way to do it without having to transform my data at all. I will follow the approach you suggest though, thanks a lot!