# Python Seaborn - Create boxplot for each numeric variable

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to build a boxplot for each numeric variable in my data set.

There is already a description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40241082/in-a-single-figure-boxplot-of-all-columns-split-by-a-label-column):

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

iris_xtab = sns.load_dataset("iris")
iris_long = pd.melt(iris, id_vars='species')
sns.boxplot(x='variable', y='value', hue='species', data=iris_long)
```

Unfortunately, the values of my data set vary very much so that I cannot fit the entire data in one graph. 
Is there are way to produce one boxplot per column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for seaborn, it is still unfamiliar, but I think it is possible by the following measures.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(iris_long, col='variable', height=9, aspect=1.5)
g.map(sns.boxplot, 'variable', 'value', hue='species', data=iris_long)
```

[image]